# Changing a tab page when pressing the back button in Xamarin.Forms and Prism

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, stack, prism, back-button

I have a Xamarin.Forms application using Prism (Xamarin.Forms v4.5.0; Prism v7.2.0).

The main application is 4 tabbed pages. Using the Prism NavigationService I can switch tabs easily using something like this - `NavigationService.SelectTabAsync("Page2");`

But if the user presses the back button, it just exits the application.

Is there a way to add the tab changes into the navigation stack so pressing back would just go to the previously selected tab?